# Can software (Steam) or system updates modify BIOS?

Tags: updates, steam, bios

thanks a lot in advance for your help. My laptop VAIO got brick **during playing** Steam on Ubuntu (14.04 LTS). It was the hottest and wetter day of the summer, I was playing for almost 4 hours and the laptop was in fact burning like hell. I shouldn't have forced it that way.

I was unable to restart it again, no lights, no switching on, no power, no nothing, removing battery, holding switch button one minute, etc. I took it to a laptop service. I thought the motherboard or the graphic card had burnt. But after two weeks the guy of the laptop service told me that it was just a BIOS problem, no hardware problem. He configured it manually and that's it. I was astonished.

Can anyone help me to know what it really happened? BIOS problem? Can Ubuntu modify BIOS during a system update or Steam doing it during playing? That's weird. Now I have fear to update the system or play Steam because I'm not sure at all of what caused it. I think that the laptop collapsed because of the heat and that corrupted the BIOS at the same time.

I would thank a lot a bit of enlightenment.

Jose

Comment: Steam can't effect your bios, likely, it got really hot and corrupted the data in the chip, it only has a certain level of stress, then when the metal gets soft, all those bits of data would move around with it. So simply re flashing the bios was all it took to fix, once it cooled. Of course no one can answer this for sure, we did not see it, so this is off topic.

Comment: How could I fix it myself if it happens again? How do I reflash the bios if I'm unable to turn it on at all?

Comment: Don't let it happen again, be careful, you got lucky, without knowing exactly what happened, I can't say how to fix it. A repair shop will have a machine of some kind to force the board to boot I am sure.

Comment: I'll be more careful and I'll control better that the temperature don't get so high again. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend [hardinfo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hardinfo). It keeps you updated on internal temperature of anything with a thermal sensor. =) Use this cmd to install: `sudo apt-get install hardinfo`

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically anything that has root on your machine can update firmware (BIOS/EFI).  Theoretically.  Practically, it is a bad idea to do.  That's why in the past you needed DOS diskettes (DOS gives 100% access without any constraints to the hardware) to update firmware.  Nowadays, BIOS/EFI often have integrated procedures, that either are in the menu or can be triggered by a program.

However, keep in mind that the chip that contains the configuration or even the program code of the firmware can be flashed.  Flashing is erasing + reprogramming.  It follows that it is indeed possible to damage your BIOS/EFI.  It is sufficient that a cell (the storage unit in firmware) got corrupted and that stops it from booting.  My theory: the overheating of the machine caused just that.  Something corrupted either the firmware configuration or the BIOS/EFI itself.

I had it happen on a Zotac Nano ID61.  When I tried upgrading to Windows 10, it was bricked after that.  Black screen on boot.  I was baffled.  While I wasn't sure, I bought a new BIOS/EFI chip (there are specialized shops that can make you one for something like 15$).  I took the defective chip out, plugged the new one in, and the machine booted at once.

I do not know whether laptops have exchangeable BIOS/EFI chips, though.  They might be soldered on.

Comment: From a very cursory Google search, it looks like laptops and desktops usually have the BIOS/EFI chip soldered on.

Comment: Makes sense.  It's cheaper.  Sometimes there still are jumpers to clear the CMOS (which contains the configuration). That's probably what the repairman did.

Comment: What's a jumper? I would love to repair my laptop on my own  if it happens again. I couldn't do anything to fix the BIOS because it didn't turn on at all

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumper_(computing)
The picture is rather crappy, but it basically is a removable switch.  If you happen to have a normal motherboard lying around, look around for the text "CMOS Reset", next to it will be a jumper like on the picture.

Comment: ... another way is to remove the CMOS battery for a long time (a few hours is usually enough), but to be frank with you: on a laptop that might so be impossibe or hard.

Comment: Thanks a lot, jawtheshark. I have looked for it and I have understood how it works. I'm not sure if I would be able to do it on my laptop because I have never opened it. But anyway it is good to know. I felt so defendless.

Comment: Do you have an exact model of your VAIO (often a model number on the bottom of the laptop).  Often it is possible to find so called "service manuals" online which help you open it up.  Furthermore, there is youtube with people showing you how. 
That said, many laptops (especially business class laptops and gaming laptops), do have panels you can easily open to install RAM or a hard disk.  If there is a jumper, it more more likely to be accessible over those panels.  However, there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

I'm alost 100% sure the problem was overheating.
The laptop's is too week for some games. The cooling system is not efficient.
And I'm almost 100% there's no program which can cause bios misconfiguration. The only thing can some programs do is to change date and time.
I don't talk about tools from manufacturing to update bios from windows/linux.
I talk about programs like steam.

Cheer's

Comment: -1 Bad grammar, unclear, lack of confidence.